# Trying to figure out the checksum algorithm for a serial interface

Tags: java, serial-port, checksum, crc

I'm trying to reverse-engineer a serial interface for a blood glucose meter.. essentially trying to upload data from a java program instead of from the meter itself (allows me to upload data from different sources).  There is some form of checksum on the data send and so far I have been unable to create code that re-creates the checksum digit (or digits) used.

I have a full communications trace of an upload from the meter to destination program

The two transmissions I've been using to check my work are as follows:

**The Date:** 06 02 30 36 31 34 31 30 30 31 36 42 04 06
... which translates to [ACK][STX]061410016B[EOT][ACK]  
The pertinent part of this transmission is the string "141001".. which stands for year=14(2014), month=10 (October), day=01 (the 1st).  
I'm not positive what the "06" at the begging of the string is.  The "B" at the end I presume is a checksum, the "6" just before it might be part of the checksum.. but seems to stay the same despite the date transmitted.

**The Time:**     06 02 30 36 30 38 33 31 30 39 36 44 04 06
... which translates to [ACK][STX]060831096D[EOT][ACK]  
The pertinent part of this transmission is the 083109 which stands for 8:31:09 AM....  
once again the string starts with 06 and ends with 6.. but this one ends with a 'D' which is presumably the checksum.

---

I've tried a number of algorithms to the best of my ability with the string in various forms 
without the ACK, without the ACK and STX, without the ACK, STX, and 06, witout the trailing '6' and all permutations of that.

I think that the leading character may refer to the number of pertinent digits.. in the date/time each have 6 pertinent digits. 
 Other transmissions seem to make that hold true

06 02 30 34 30 39 31 30 36 36 04 06   [ACK][STX]04091066[EOT][ACK] 
         (Starts with 04.. has 4 digits then 2 trailing digits)

06 02 30 38 31 34 38 39 34 34 39 35 36 36 04 06   [ACK][STX]081489449566[EOT][ACK] (Starts with 08, has 8 digits with 2 trailing digits)

but others later don't necessarily fall in line.

    02 31 32 30 31 33 32 31 31 33 37 32 35 30 39 31 34 30 30 30 30 36 31 03    [STX]1201321137250914000061[ETX]  
the portions of this string that I know matter are 
   
132: the reading
   
1137: 11:37 AM
   
250914: September 25th, 2014

so this has neither 12 digits or 120.. so that's a mystery

I've run out of ideas to try.. anyone with more experience with check digits have a guess? possibly some sort of CRC? I can provide more examples if necessary

**UPDATE:** The order of the characters does not seem to matter, when I send the time it accepts the time as it was sent in the original stack trace:  [ACK][STX]060831096D[EOT][ACK]  but it also accepts [ACK][STX]060931086D[EOT][ACK]  IE, I can switch the seconds and the minutes without affecting the checksum apparently.. I *think* this rules out CRC as well as some other checksum standards...

changing this character *does not* seem to have an effect on the checksum either, as changing it to a 7 is not rejected by the other side. [ACK][STX]0**6**0831096D[EOT][ACK]

changing this character *does* cause the other side to reject the record.. so it's either used in the checksum or is part of the checksum.. but of the 300-400 records I saw go across it was a 6 in all of them.  [ACK][STX]06083109**6**D[EOT][ACK]

Comment: I bet the first byte is a packet type.

Comment: there is a [Patent for a device to monitor Glucose Levels](http://www.google.com/patents/US20100240979) that has a CRC algorithm.. you may check if is the same Device or try to find your Device's patent...

Comment: I've looked into that a little bit.. I think the problem with CRC is I just flat don't understand it.  I've written interfaces for some high-end labratory equipment before and their checksums have never be horribly complicated.  I think the most common one  I've seen has been ([sum of digits]%256)%16

Comment: ([sum of digits]%256)%16 is just (sum of digits) & 0xF. You're right that it can't be a CRC. Have you considered an XOR of the digits?

Comment: Tried this (the date) with different permutations of the string (with/without characters) , but it didn't get me the `String s2 = "093108";
        <BR>byte[] ba = s2.getBytes();
        <BR>byte xorChecksum = 0;  
        <BR>for(int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++){  
        <BR>    xorChecksum ^= ba[i];  
        <BR>}
        <BR>System.out.println(xorChecksum);`

Comment: @jrlambs OK now try it with an initial value of 0xff.

Comment: @EJP changing byte xorChecksum = 0; to byte xorChecksum = (byte)0xff; basically just gives me negative values out of the above algorithm with input of "093108" i get -6

Comment: Well keep trying. I would think whatever it is is computed over the entire message between the STX and EOT, both exclusive, but including the lengths. Curious that it is using EOT instead of ETX.

Comment: Yeah.. the protocol is just weird.. the vast majority of the communication doesn't use the transmission characters at all, when the other side responds it indicates it is done with a CR.. stupid.  Anyway, I think i got it cracked!  you were correct that it was an XOR... that exact code above worked.. but with a starting byte set to int 14.... I just let it loop through all o the possible starting values and found which one matched ont he first string.. then put in the second string and the same one matched..... can I mark your comment as the right answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an XOR over just the meaningful part of the string.  Thanks to @EJP for pointing me in the right direction.

For the Date I send in the bolded part to the function [ACK][STX]06**141001**6B[EOT][ACK] 

The getChecksum function returns "B"

The function looks like this

```
private static String getChecksum(String s){
    int i = 14;
    byte xorChecksum = (byte)i;
    byte[] ba = s.getBytes();
    for(int j = 0; j < ba.length; j++){  
        xorChecksum ^= ba[j];  
    }
    Byte b = new Byte(xorChecksum);
    System.out.println("i: "+i+" - "+b.intValue());
    return toHex(b.intValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

([sum of digits]%256)%16 is just (sum of digits) & 0xF. You're right that it can't be a CRC. It must be either a sum or an XOR of the digits. Try XOR with starting values other than zero. I would think whatever it is is computed over the entire message between the STX and EOT, both exclusive, but try it both excluding and including the lengths.

Curious that it is using EOT instead of ETX.